# How can I draw a scatter plot with a stairstep line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, while I'm trying to mimic a [shiny web app](https://twise.shinyapps.io/RshinyPracticalADAV/), 
I found a plot I would like to create, which looks like a scatter plot with a stairstep line using the `diamonds` dataset.
According to the web app, the stairstep can be adjusted by a specific number.

I can handle the scatter plot with `geom_point()`.
However, when it comes to stairstep line, I've tried `geom_step()` but I couldn't make it.

```r
require(ggplot2)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price, y=carat, color=cut))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Spectral') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,2500,5000,7500,10000),
                     limits = c(0,10000)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,3),
                     breaks = c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3.0))
#> Warning: Removed 5225 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Below is what I want to make.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  How do you want the steps to be defined?  What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  ("I couldn't make it" isn't specific enough.)

Comment: @Limey Thanks for your advice. I added a reproducible example codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it was done something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, carat)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cut)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_step(data = diamonds %>%
              mutate(breaks = cut(price, breaks = 7)) %>%
              group_by(breaks) %>%
              summarize(carat = mean(carat),
                        price = range(price)),
            color = "green2", size = 1.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The web app is a little bit confusing, because stepwise regression usually refers to feature selection in a linear model.
However, you can get the steps by grouping the data and summarizing the groups to be plotted with `geom_step` e.g. to have 5 equidistant intervals:

```r
library(tidyverse)

n_intervals <- 5

diamonds %>%
  arrange(price) %>%
  mutate(group = cut(price, n_intervals + 1)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(price = mean(price), carat = mean(carat)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(price, carat)) +
    geom_step()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>